# Put codereview.se in the suggested off-topic sites

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Since I registered myself on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), I've spotted many questions which belong on that site instead of on Stack Overflow.

I think it would be useful if we added that site to the list of sites in the Off-topic reason, since it has many similarities with Stack Overflow.

Comment: Code Review needs to go out of Beta before that can happen. Once it is out of beta, there needs to be care that not all bad SO questions end up there, as happened with Programmers.

Comment: @Oded Migrations from SO to Code Review are nowhere near as complicated. There's a pretty clear-cut distinction between the sites, so I wouldn't be too worried about repeating the past here. :)

Comment: @Oded: Specifically, 1.) there must be some real code (no pseudocode), 2.) specific questions must directly relate to the code, and 3.) asking for new code is not allowed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We don't set up migration paths to sites that are still in beta. When Code Review graduates, we can revisit the off-topic list on Stack Overflow.

Comment: yes, we need to wait until stable is out, of course (I hadn't seen that). We can keep this question as a reminder.

Comment: Should it not be [meta-tag:status-planned] or [meta-tag:status-deferred]?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Meh. At the moment, the request is declined.